# Is there a FlowDocument text processor control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, rich-text-editor, flowdocument

I need to make a sort of text processor. It must have these features:

- All the WordPad features + paragraph styles like MS Word + text
  columns + Zoom.
- Insertion of tables, images, and controls like buttons, checkboxes.
- Text search and replacement, spell check.
- Syntax coloring, like code or quote parts on the StackOverflow site.
- Ability to move text paragraph on custom places via mouse (like OneNote)
- Ability to add some simple diagram (hierarchic)

I found on the web that the best way to implement the above requirements is to use `FlowDocument`. I also found that WPF `RichTextControl` would have many required functionalities, but on StackOverflow it is written that it has bad performance.

So, does it exist a FlowDocument text processor control?

If not, from which control could I start in order to implement the above requirements?

Comment: It took me a while to edit your post to make it at least English-compliant... I'm not rude by nature, but man, please subscribe to some English class :) . Now, 2 questions: 1) why don't you simply use MS Word, instead of re-inventing the wheel? The time/cost it would take to you to write a similar application is hundred of times the cost of a license of MS Word. For special functions, you can search for Word plugins. 2) have you tried a `RichTextControl` on your own with some experiments before rejecting it? Maybe its performance are suitable for you case, but nobody can know until you try.

Comment: 1) Hm, I didn`t think about Word usage. But in any case I need save all data in databases. The data must be split by type and saved in databases. After that data will be indexing. So I think the time/cost for Word/FlowDocument would be almost similar. I think FlowDocument is not so complex for my requirements. Only with 5,6,7 required items I have problems.

Comment: 2) No RichTextControl I didn't try because there are a lot of bad feedback in internet about performance. But you right, I will try it. I don`t start the development before find the best start point.